# playing video in UItableView cell swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to play a video in TableView Cell.I'm using this code but when I run nothing will appear.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let myCell:UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCell")!
    let videoURL = NSURL(string: "http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4")
    let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL! as URL)
    let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)

    playerLayer.frame = myCell.bounds
    myCell.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
    player.play()

    return myCell
}
```

Comment: In think you forgot to enable `App Transport Security` so please use http://stackoverflow.com/a/33712228/1142743  to enable it

Comment: Thank you so much.It worked.

Comment: I added my answer please accept it. so for others it will be useful

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/33712228/1142743

Comment: There is something fundamentally wrong with the code. You'll be adding extra video player layers every time you a cell is reused. I suggest creating a custom cell that already has a videoplayer as a part of it. Or one videoplayer that runs in all the cells

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my previous comment Please enable App transport security in info.plist .

Here are the settings visually:

[image]

Comment: It's me  one who commented . I adding it as answer so for others it will be useful

Comment: i changed my answer to give pictorial representation

Comment: @EricAya Please stop commenting to my answers

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127365/discussion-between-vinodh-and-eric-aya).

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to info.plist and allow App Transport Security.